# Unable to join to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, multi-index

I have two df. The first df is a multiindex and the other one is typical single index.

[image]

Figure 1: Multiindex df

and

[image]

Figure 2: Single indexing

Upon join these two df, I got the following error

> cannot join with no overlapping index names

I suspect, this error due to the index column **name** in the first df (Figure 1).

Even, swaping the index name and typical numeric value also does not help

[image]

Figure 2: Multiindex df

May I know how to address this error?

Thanks in advance for the time taken

Comment: Join by default merges on identical indexes. Can you show your second dataframe as well?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I attached it as shown in Figure 2 @adrianp

Comment: Can you show us your code? Perhaps `merge` may be appropriate as I don't think you have identical indexes.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of your datasets, instead copy/paste the text data into the question.

Comment: A [mre] please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert first level in `MultiIndex` to column before `merge`:

```
df = (df1.reset_index(level=0)
         .merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
         .set_index('name', append=True)
         .swaplevel(1, 0))
```

Or if use join:

```
df = df1.reset_index(level=0).join(df2).set_index('name', append=True).swaplevel(1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. By your proposal, I left with a single indexing df then?. How can I maintain the multi-indexing?

Comment: @polosepian -Then is necessary create MultiIndex back, answer was edited.

Comment: Thanks Jezrael for your help, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do a function such as df.rolling(window).cov()/df.rolling(window).var() where you are trying to basically merge two multi-index dataframes what happened to me was I had to specify a name to the index as it doesn't know they name of the index to match on which is why you are getting this error. If you are using something like yfin to get data you won't run into this issue because the index always defaults as 'Date'. Here is a simple one-liner to fix this:

> df.index.rename('Date', inplace=True)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).